# Remote connection on Ubuntu from windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use remote desktop from Windows 7 to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3934/is-it-possible-to-use-remote-desktop-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu)

Hi,
   I have just finish installation of desktop Ubuntu 10.10 on my new machine.
Now i want to make remote desktop connection from my windows7 network laptop. I don't want to connect to monitor in ubuntu machine.

Is there any way to do this?

I want to do - 
1. Start the ubuntu machine
2. Make remote connection on ubuntu machine from win 7 laptop 
3. Start working

I have enabled remote connection on my ubuntu machine.

Thanks in advanve for help.

Comment: The duped question is for 10.04 but it shouldn't be different. Let me know if it is and we'll split it into version-specific questions, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, and this is what I use on my systems is NX or FreeNX. This is a full desktop remote access client. NX (www.nomachine.com) has both the server and the client software that can be installed. The server portion (along with the node portion and the client) can be installed on the server. You also need to install OpenSSH. Synaptics can do this for you.

Once the sevrer is installed, you can install the client only, on any any client computer. There are client for Linux, Windows and Mac OS X.

Once the client is installed on the remote client, you start it, give your hostname/IP address and port (if not 22). Provide your user credentials, just as when you login locally. You are in business.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easily do that using VNC, what you have to do is set up the VNC server on Ubuntu, I think it just requires enabling it,  and then use a VNC client on the windows machine, Perhaps someone with more experience can expand a bit as I don't remember how to enable it, and am not on my Ubuntu machine at the moment... if I get to it before anyone else I will edit my answer.

Comment: Already enabled remote connection on ubuntu

Comment: Okay then you need to install a program like VNC viewer on windows and use your computer's (ubuntu) local ip address to access it.

Answer (score 0):

spooky, second question like this ive answered today:

[Is it possible to use remote desktop from Windows 7 to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3934/is-it-possible-to-use-remote-desktop-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu-10-04/8717#8717)