# Failed to load session "ubuntu-2d

Tags: remote-desktop

I tried remotely connecting to Ubuntu 12.04 from windows 7 using remote desktop manager. After installing xrdp, I was able to login but was not able to see any icon on my Ubuntu Desktop. Even the right click does not work.
This problem is same as referenced in the following link:

[Blank desktop when logging in via xrdp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91657/blank-desktop-when-logging-in-via-xrdp)

To get rid of this problem, I followed the following steps:

```
cd /home/youruser
echo "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > .xsession
sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart
```

But now, I am not even able to login the Ubuntu system. It displays a message "Failed to load session "ubuntu-2d".
Don't know how to get rid of this problem. Searched on internet but was not able to get any significant answer.
Thanks in advance for the help !!!

Answer (score 1):

I used the following:

```
gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback
```

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3518

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same problem on a new laptop with high resolution screen. I changed the resolution in the windows remote desktop client to a lower level 800x600 and reduced the color depth to 24 bits. After this change the Ubuntu desktop was shown (after login).

Note: Ubuntu 12.04 + I tried gnome-session suggestions first.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. In my case, the unity package had been removed during the upgrade + autoremove.

```
apt-get install unity unity-2d
```

solved the problem