# Login screen freezed after resume

Tags: unity, login, google-chrome, lightdm

Today I came into strange problem. Yesterday, as always, I suspended my Ubuntu 14.04 (Unity) laptop for night. Today as I open it up it shows login screen (lightdm) but it is impossible to write password in. I see password field but it is not editable (the coursor does not blink; I do not see dots as I type). I am able to move the mouse coursor. Also, I am able to login into terminal by CTRL+ALT+F1. As I run the "top" command I see that my (not root) process "init" uses 100% CPU.

It would not be such a big issue since I can restart lightdm. However, the main problem is I have opened several Chrome Incognito windows with important tabs in it. I would like to somehow get access to these windows and save open tabs. Is it possible?

I see two solutions:

1. Somehow unfreeze login screen to normally login.
2. Forget about login and somehow save Chrome Incognito sessions from the terminal.

Unfortunately I do not know how to do this. I would be very gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Well do the following. Do not logout from anywhere.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
2. Log on to `tty`.
3. Install remote desktop to your computer.

   `$ sudo apt-get install xrdp`
4. Log on to Ubuntu with another computer. Use `$ ifconfig` to list your `IP`.
   [image: Login]
   [image: Login]
5. Save all you **incognito tabs** (right-click on a tab and select "Bookmark all tabs" or hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).
6. On your `tty` shell, execute

   `$ sudo service lightdm restart`
7. You should be logged out of Unity and the login screen would be unfrozen.

**Why the workaround?** Chromium developers went to a lot of trouble to ensure that Chromium does not save any state information in **incognito mode**. It's probably possible to write a script to get all open tabs, even incognito, but that'll only get you the URLs. Not worth the effort in my opinion. I would sill like to see if somebody can show how to do it that way.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try it in a moment. I have thought of a remote desktop solution but it seemed to me that as my desktop is not available it will not work.

Comment: About your last comment, I would love to know a way to do that.

Comment: You just need another computer. The support is built in on windows. For another Ubuntu PC, try http://www.7tutorials.com/connecting-windows-remote-desktop-ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. I do not want to break anything so I will ask here. I use Unity desktop with lightdm. Should I set xsession as provided here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91657/blank-desktop-when-logging-in-via-xrdp?

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work for me. As far as I understand, I need to use xrdp with vino. After login via xrdp I see only grey background. I think this is related to some problem with DISPLAY, because in terminal I get error message about DISPLAY in X11.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have the same problem since a few weeks.
Sometimes I can't type the password at the cursor, even when I click there. The workaround is then to click in the top right corner of the screen and select "switch account"; an unfrozen login screen appears.

Sometimes there is no button or place to type or any user interface elements for that matter, just my username and a frozen screen. The workaround I found for this is this: have a guest session running next to normal session. Then use ctrl-alt-F8 to switch to this guest session, something I found out to be possible. Then this takes a while, and then switch account. Then there is an unfrozen login screen.

Only works if there is already a guest session open.

Oh yeah also the computer now doesn't wake up when I open the lit, I have to click the power button.

Everything takes 10 times as long as normal and this is a mayor headache bug, since before it took about 2-3 seconds to resume my session, now I must pay attention not to close my lit if I may need my computer fast at some point, which is, generally, always.

Ubuntu 14.04, thinkpad t440s w/ touchscreen