# Lost xrdp remote desktop connection Ubuntu Server on Azure from windows

Tags: 14.04, server, remote-desktop, xrdp, azure

My problem is similiar to: [Blank desktop when logging in via xrdp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91657/blank-desktop-when-logging-in-via-xrdp)
But I am also loosing the connection.

I have an Ubuntu 14 Server VM in Microsoft Azure Cloud. And my laptop is Win8 X64.

I am able to access to the VM console via SSH by Putty.

I followed these instructions to make server accesible via mstsc (windows remote):

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop 
$ sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

I set an end-point for port 3389.

I can make a remote connection and see the xrdp login window. I chose sesman-Xvnc Module and login with my credentials.

Then see this window:
[image: XRDP-loggin-details-window]

And then an empty gray window with a cursor:
[image]

**After in a few seconds my connection is lost with no message or something. What could be the reason?**

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have this now too. Any luck? Did you ever fix it?

Comment: No, I didn't try so much to solve it. But I know that there is a person who has solved. I asked him to help you. Maybe he answers here soon.

Comment: I tried it again a day later. And now I am not losing the connection as before, but it still just sits there and the Ubuntu Desktop (Unity?) never starts.

Answer (score 0):

possibly an old post but this might be helpful to other.

Unity Desktop is not supported by xRDP software package on Ubuntu
You have to install an alternative desktop interface.  A good alternative is the mate-desktop

You can install the mate-desktop using the following command

> sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment
>   mate-notification-daemon

Then you can install your xrdp package

> sudo apt-get install xrdp

*Note :
On Azure, you will need to create the endpoint in order to access your Ubuntu VM using the xrdp software on the port 3389*

There is post that will describe the process of installing xrdp on Ubuntu Server 16.04. Check this [link](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=9333) for part I - Part II should be coming soon

Hope this is helpful