# Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome desktop does not start

Tags: 20.04, gnome, xrdp

System boots but not the desktop. I can remote login to PC and get a desktop, but there is no desktop starting on the main monitor. I just see a blinking cursor in the top of the screen. I can change to a different terminal and log in from there, but I can't get the desktop to appear.

It used to work but after setting up XRDP is does not any more. And now I can't get back to a working state.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a ASROCK J5005 and using gnome.

Any suggestions?

Kind regards,
Christian

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91657/blank-desktop-when-logging-in-via-xrdp Check if this helps.

Comment: I did make a difference. In my .xsession file I only had "gnome-session" without an option.  After adding "--session=ubuntu-2d" it now starts the desktop but in kinda strange way. Instead of opening up directly in the desktop there is a xfce4 like login screen, and only after typing in my password do I get to the desktop.
But after adding the option the remote login does no longer work. Connection is rejected

Comment: Ideally I want one desktop (e.g. gnome) and that that desktop instance is accessible either directly on the PC or remote. It should be the same instance, so if I leave home having worked on programming then I can remote login and pick up from where I left (I want to see the exact same screen remote as I when I left the PC)