# How do I remote desktop to Linux (Ubuntu) from Windows?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use remote desktop from Windows 7 to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3934/is-it-possible-to-use-remote-desktop-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu)

I see folks have asked how to remote desktop from Ubuntu to Windows, but not vice versa.  How can I remote desktop from Windows (7) to Ubuntu?  If there's no native support, what tools do I need to download and install.