# Remote Desktop Connection from Windows 7 to Ubuntu

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, remote-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to use remote desktop from Windows 7 to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3934/is-it-possible-to-use-remote-desktop-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu)

I am new to ubuntu - I have my personal laptop on UBUNTU and work on WIN 7 PC at my office.
Can you please tell me how to do a desktop connection to my home laptop from office? I have a wireless router at home and the laptop connects to internet through the router. Please let me know of a solution.