# Windows Work >>Ubuntu Studio Home

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Is it possible for me to be to access my Windows PC at work so I can move files and check my emails from home on my Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The technology for that is called VNC.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing
However, you will have to leave your Windows PC running over the night. An alternative to VNC is RDP.

I also believe this here might help you as well:
[Is it possible to use remote desktop from Windows 7 to Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3934/is-it-possible-to-use-remote-desktop-from-windows-7-to-ubuntu)

Comment: I personally like [Remmina](http://www.remmina.org/wp/) for managing remote sessions. I believe it handles VNC and RDP

Comment: Yeah, Remmina is an option. You can install it by copy pasting 'sudo apt install remmina' in the terminal or by searching for remmina in the software center.

Comment: Consider that this distinct possibility might be totally denied by employers security protocols .

Comment: Employer security can theoretically deny anything. Most good sysadmins work on a 'ban everything then whitelist' policy.